# What is "recovery time" on CY74FCT191T datasheet

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet

Looking through TI's [CY74FCT191T datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cy74fct191t.pdf) I found this line :

\$t_{rec}\$ recovery time | #PL after CLK↑ | 4.5 ns

I hesitate between two interpretations of this line, #PL loading data during it's falling transition :

- #PL shouldn't fall counting 4.5 ns from the CLK rising edge
- #PL shouldn't be low counting 4.5 ns the CLK rising edge

How to interpret  this datasheet line ? Or in general, what does *recovery time* means in IC's datasheet (not diode reverse recovery time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does recovery time mean in ICs datasheet?

In this case we are talking about data latches that latch data on the rise or falling edge of the CLK for that section. They indicate that /PL will only function if those time boundaries are met. /PL stands for Parallel Load, which is asynchronous to the clock 'CP'.They indicate  the time for rising /PL recovers to allow a new CP, or clock pulse. That is /PL must be high for Trec time before a new clock pulse, or data output is unknown.

Also a data change when clock is changing could result in ambiguous data, a 'metastable state', so they are giving you the 'window' width in nS in which /PL will not work correctly. They are actually telling you not to do a parallel load during this window when the CP clk might also be changing the count value.

It is in effect a 'keep-out' window. Do not use CP inside this window of 'n' ns when /PL is low.

HINT: This IC counts on the rising edge of the clock 'CP', so you can use the falling edge to enable the /PL signal. This way they will not collide at the same time. A simple OR gate would work. By the way, the /PL signal overrides the CP clk, so it is up to you to decide which function is most important while the clock is running.

Comment: So basically it means /PL should not fall during \$t_{rec}\$ ?

Comment: That is correct. It may result in an unknown output count value.

Comment: The wording is incorrect ... "They indicate that /PL will not function if those time boundaries are not met."  **It is the opposite** and indicates when for t< Trec, CP will not function.   It should say **"They indicate the the time for rising PL# recovers to allow CP"** or   PL# off to CP  ( deadzone) also units [ns] not [nS nanosiemens]  ( but later you define ok)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75. Thanks for the tip. Tripped over my own brain on that, at least how I worded it. Should make sense now. Btw, I see time represented as mS/uS/nS, so I am confused if that is wrong.

Comment: I once made the same misteak,, which is why I like to prevent others seeing the same err.  s is seconds , **capitals are always reserved for proper names** as in this case Siemens inverse of Ohms  only exception is MS = microsoft ;)

Answer (score 0):

For this device, rather than as a general term, it's referring to the minimum time for which /PL must be negated before the next CLK rising edge.

In other words, a low-high transition of /PL must not occur in the trec before to a CLK rising edge.

If /PL is allowed to rise during trec, violating this timing specification, the internal flip-flops could go metastable or store the wrong bit value.